# Debug failing transaction on mainnet

Tags: contract-debugging

We have a smart contract deployed on main net and some of the recent transactions have started failing. Any idea how we can start debugging the contract?

Contract address: 0x81EAF1fF62BB8ccaa5314287B14e75E04E21b8F2

Most recent three transactions that have failed
0x7ea699902c6a4be61d0037baaabbb8be5269cb2956c2fe617e88b82304aba615
0x1e29f225021bc9f9c886bdcb1a5a69af98ae5b7821773c40f0ad23a82975c8e5
0xbe4853a7d079ef35e88bdb3c5e2f44ced4263d13ced64563143514400a342b1b

Comment: Use [Tenderly](https://tenderly.co/).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone finding this, hopefully this can help.

I've been using tenderly because I have trouble reading the geth debug 2 tool on the scan sites and am currently debugging an issue myself.

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/

When my transaction just says 'failed' it gives me a bit clearer details on why unless it has reverted immediately.

I am by no means an expert, but for the first 3 hashes of this question they all basically reverted after the contract was called.

In many cases this usually means that the **input parameters** are not correct when passing through a contract and/or the contract **tried to do some computation** and failed immediately.

A very specific example for myself was when I sent bytes to my contract and decoded them incorrectly.

```
function encodeStuff(
        address myAddress,
        uint256 amount, 
        address someAddress,
        bytes calldata swapData
    ) external  {

        bytes memory data = abi.encode(myAddress, amount, someAddress, swapData);
  
    }
```

Then in another function when decoding I tried to unpack the swapData bytes with **everything**:

```
        (
         address myAddress,
         uint256 amount, 
         address someAddress,
         address someAddress1,
         address someAddress2,
         address someAddress3,
         address someAddress4,
         bytes memory extra_data1,
         address token_address,
         bytes memory extra_data2

        ) = abi.decode(swapdata, 
        ( 
            address
            uint256
            address
            address, 
            address, 
            address,
            address,
            bytes, 
            address, 
            bytes
        ));
```

Because I did this, the transaction reverted immediately when it saw there was no extra data to decode from `bytes memory data`.

I actually needed to decode twice.

```
// First decode data to get swapData bytes
(address myAddress, uint256 amount, address someAddress, bytes memory swapData) = abi.decode(data, (address, uint256, address, bytes));

// Now decode swapData
(
         address someAddress1,
         address someAddress2,
         address someAddress3,
         address someAddress4,
         bytes memory extra_data1,
         address token_address,
         bytes memory extra_data2

        ) = abi.decode(swapdata, 
        (
            address, 
            address, 
            address,
            address,
            bytes, 
            address, 
            bytes
        ));
```

This problem is very specific but the error would show up on scan sites and tenderly just like the hashes in this question, 'Failed' with not much extra data.

If I ever learn more in depth methods of debugging that don't require an arm or leg, I'll update this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `seth debug <txhash>` with dapptools on a forked mainnet!